# Removal of billboards from given ones

Tags: algorithm

I came across this question

> ADZEN is a very popular advertising firm in your city. In every road
>   you can see their advertising billboards. Recently they are facing a
>   serious   challenge , MG Road the most used and beautiful road in your
>   city has been   almost filled by the billboards and this is having a
>   negative effect on
>       the natural view.
>           On people's demand ADZEN has decided to remove some of the billboards
>        in such a way that there are no more than K billboards standing together 
>       in any part of the road.
>           You may assume the MG Road to be a straight line with N billboards.Initially there is no gap between any two adjecent
>   billboards.
>           ADZEN's primary income comes from these billboards so the billboard removing process has to be done in such a way that the
>   billboards 
>       remaining at end should give maximum possible profit among all possible   final configurations.Total profit of a configuration is the
>   sum of the profit values of all billboards present in that
>   configuration.
>           Given N,K and the profit value of each of the N billboards, output the maximum profit that can be obtained from the remaining
>   billboards under the conditions given.
>
> Input description
>
> 1st line contain two space seperated integers N and K. Then follow N lines describing the profit value of each billboard i.e ith
>   line contains   the profit value of ith billboard.
>
> ```
>     Sample Input
>     6 2 
>     1
>     2
>     3
>     1
>     6
>     10 
>
>     Sample Output
>     21
> ```
>
> Explanation
>
> In given input there are 6 billboards and after the process no more than 2 should be together. So remove 1st and 4th
>   billboards giving a configuration _ 2 3 _ 6 10 having a profit of 21.
>   No other configuration has a profit more than 21.So the answer is 21.
>
> ```
>     Constraints
>     1 <= N <= 1,00,000(10^5)
>     1 <= K <= N
>     0 <= profit value of any billboard <= 2,000,000,000(2*10^9)
> ```

I think that we have to select minimum cost board in first k+1 boards and  then repeat the same untill last,but this was not giving correct answer 
for  all cases. 
i tried upto my knowledge,but unable to find solution.
        if any one got idea please kindly share your thougths.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to find maximum sum of elements in an array such that not more than k elements are adjacent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045944/algorithm-to-find-maximum-sum-of-elements-in-an-array-such-that-not-more-than-k)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Mine does! ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a typical DP problem. Lets say that P(n,k) is the maximum profit of having k billboards up to the position n on the road. Then you have following formula:

```
 P(n,k) = max(P(n-1,k), P(n-1,k-1) + C(n))
 P(i,0) = 0 for i = 0..n
```

Where  c(n) is the profit from putting the nth billboard on the road. Using that formula to calculate P(n, k) bottom up you'll get the solution in O(nk) time.

I'll leave up to you to figure out why that formula holds.

**edit**

Dang, I misread the question.

It still is a DP problem, just the formula is different. Let's say that P(v,i) means the maximum profit at point v where last cluster of billboards has size i.
Then P(v,i) can be described using following formulas:

```
P(v,i) = P(v-1,i-1) + C(v) if i > 0 
P(v,0) = max(P(v-1,i) for i = 0..min(k, v)) 
P(0,0) = 0
```

You need to find `max(P(n,i) for i = 0..k))`.

Comment: i can't understand this "k billboards upto the position n ",can you please elaborate.here what is k? .Is it the value given in input(i.e) atmost k billboards are consequetive

Comment: imagine that the road is a integer axis. In each point you can either have the billboard standing or not. So "k billboards up to the position n" means that you have k billboards put in some positions up to the position n. Ie. 3 billboards up to the position 5 means either: `BB_B_` or `B_B_B` or `BBB__` etc...

Comment: how you will check that atmost k are grouped or not.and also mention that the k value given in problem and you mentioned are same or not

Comment: is there any way to optimize ur soln? Using this soln only solves 4 of the 10 cases and rest gets time limit exceeded error. dint wanna start a new question for this.

Comment: @AccessDenied sorry for late reply. I'll see what I can do after work

Comment: @soulcheck How can this solution be optimized?

Comment: This solution __is__ optimized. To speed things up, keep profit values inside a table (that is the meaning of DP anyway), because P(v, i) for a particular v and i is getting calculated multiple times. That way time is not the problem but it gives std::bad_alloc (i.e. unable to allocate memory) for two big inputs. But it passes 8 test cases.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is one of the challenges posted in www.interviewstreet.com ...

I'm happy to say I got this down recently, but not quite satisfied and wanted to see if there's a better method out there.

soulcheck's DP solution above is straightforward, but won't be able to solve this completely due to the fact that K can be as big as N, meaning the DP complexity will be O(NK) for both runtime and space.

Another solution is to do branch-and-bound, keeping track the best sum so far, and prune the recursion if at some level, that is, if currSumSoFar + SUM(a[currIndex..n)) <= bestSumSoFar ... then exit the function immediately, no point of processing further when the upper-bound won't beat best sum so far.

The branch-and-bound above got accepted by the tester for all but 2 test-cases.
Fortunately, I noticed that the 2 test-cases are using small K (in my case, K < 300), so the DP technique of O(NK) suffices.

Comment: The DP technique is fast enough. I am getting std::bad_alloc though, :(.

Answer (score 1):

soulcheck's (second) DP solution is correct in principle. There are two improvements you can make using these observations:

1) It is unnecessary to allocate the entire DP table. You only ever look at two rows at a time.

2) For each row (the v in P(v, i)), you are only interested in the i's which most increase the max value, which is one more than each i that held the max value in the previous row. Also, i = 1, otherwise you never consider blanks.

Answer (score 1):

I coded it in c++ using DP in O(nlogk).
Idea is to maintain a multiset with next k values for a given position. This multiset will typically have k values in mid processing. Each time you move an element and push new one. Art is how to maintain this list to have the profit[i] + answer[i+2]. More details on set:

```
/*
 * Observation 1: ith state depends on next k states i+2....i+2+k
 * We maximize across this states added on them "accumulative" sum
 *
 * Let Say we have list of numbers of state i+1, that is list of {profit + state solution}, How to get states if ith solution
 *
 * Say we have following data k = 3
 *
 * Indices:     0   1   2   3   4
 * Profits:     1   3   2   4   2
 * Solution:    ?   ?   5   3   1
 *
 * Answer for [1] = max(3+3, 5+1, 9+0) = 9
 *
 * Indices:     0   1   2   3   4
 * Profits:     1   3   2   4   2
 * Solution:    ?   9   5   3   1
 *
 * Let's find answer for [0], using set of [1].
 *
 * First, last entry should be removed. then we have (3+3, 5+1)
 *
 * Now we should add 1+5, but entries should be incremented with 1
 *      (1+5, 4+3, 6+1) -> then find max.
 *
 *  Could we do it in other way but instead of processing list. Yes, we simply add 1 to all elements
 *
 *  answer is same as: 1 + max(1-1+5, 3+3, 5+1)
 *
 */
```

---

```
ll dp()
{
multiset<ll, greater<ll> > set;

mem[n-1] = profit[n-1];

ll sumSoFar = 0;

lpd(i, n-2, 0)
{
    if(sz(set) == k)
        set.erase(set.find(added[i+k]));

    if(i+2 < n)
    {
        added[i] = mem[i+2] - sumSoFar;
        set.insert(added[i]);
        sumSoFar += profit[i];
    }

    if(n-i <= k)
        mem[i] = profit[i] + mem[i+1];
    else 
        mem[i] = max(mem[i+1], *set.begin()+sumSoFar);
}

return mem[0];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This looks like a linear programming problem.</strike> This problem would be linear, but for the requirement that no more than K adjacent billboards may remain.

See wikipedia for a general treatment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Visit your university library to find a good textbook on the subject.

There are many, many libraries to assist with linear programming, so I suggest you do not attempt to code an algorithm from scratch. Here is a list relevant to Python: http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Libraries

Comment: It's apparent from the question that it's meant to be "coded from scratch". It's looks like something that would show up in a Java programming challenge.

Comment: @LastCoder: Perhaps. In any case, this is the acme of what you should not code from scratch (almost on a par with crypto code), because it's easy to get wrong.

Comment: Nope, you can not formulate constraints into canonical form, therefore, it is not LP.

Comment: @IvorPrebeg Do you just ignore the parts of answers that make your comments invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Let `P[i]` (where i=1..n) be the maximum profit for billboards `1..i` IF WE REMOVE billboard `i`. It is trivial to calculate the answer knowing all P[i]. The baseline algorithm for calculating P[i] is as follows:

```
for i=1,N
{
  P[i]=-infinity;
  for j = max(1,i-k-1)..i-1
  {
    P[i] = max( P[i], P[j] + C[j+1]+..+C[i-1] );
  }
}
```

Now the idea that allows us to speed things up. Let's say we have two different valid configurations of billboards `1` through `i` only, let's call these configurations `X1` and `X2`. If billboard `i` is removed in configuration `X1` and `profit(X1) >= profit(X2)` then we should always prefer configuration `X1` for billboards `1..i` (by `profit()` I meant the profit from billboards `1..i` only, regardless of configuration for `i+1..n`). This is as important as it is obvious.

---

We introduce a doubly-linked list of tuples `{idx,d}`: `{{idx1,d1}, {idx2,d2}, ..., {idxN,dN}}`.

- `p->idx` is index of the last billboard removed. `p->idx` is increasing as we go through the list: `p->idx < p->next->idx`
- `p->d` is the sum of elements `(C[p->idx]+C[p->idx+1]+..+C[p->next->idx-1])` if `p` is not the last element in the list. Otherwise it is the sum of elements up to the current position minus one: `(C[p->idx]+C[p->idx+1]+..+C[i-1])`.

Here is the algorithm:

---

```
P[1] = 0;
list.AddToEnd( {idx=0, d=C[0]} );
// sum of elements starting from the index at top of the list
sum = C[0]; // C[list->begin()->idx]+C[list->begin()->idx+1]+...+C[i-1]
for i=2..N
{
  if( i - list->begin()->idx > k + 1 ) // the head of the list is "too far"
  {
    sum = sum - list->begin()->d
    list.RemoveNodeFromBeginning()
  }
  // At this point the list should containt at least the element
  // added on the previous iteration. Calculating P[i].
  P[i] = P[list.begin()->idx] + sum
  // Updating list.end()->d and removing "unnecessary nodes"
  // based on the criterion described above
  list.end()->d = list.end()->d + C[i]
  while(
    (list is not empty) AND
    (P[i] >= P[list.end()->idx] + list.end()->d - C[list.end()->idx]) )
  {
    if( list.size() > 1 )
    {
      list.end()->prev->d += list.end()->d
    }
    list.RemoveNodeFromEnd();
  }
  list.AddToEnd( {idx=i, d=C[i]} );
  sum = sum + C[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//shivi..coding is adictive!!
#include<stdio.h>

long long int arr[100001];
long long  int sum[100001];
long long  int including[100001],excluding[100001];
long long int maxim(long long int a,long long int b)
{if(a>b) return a;return b;}

int main()
{
int N,K;
scanf("%d%d",&N,&K);
for(int i=0;i<N;++i)scanf("%lld",&arr[i]);

sum[0]=arr[0];
including[0]=sum[0];
excluding[0]=sum[0];
for(int i=1;i<K;++i)
{
    sum[i]+=sum[i-1]+arr[i];
    including[i]=sum[i];
    excluding[i]=sum[i];
}

long long int maxi=0,temp=0;
for(int i=K;i<N;++i)
{
    sum[i]+=sum[i-1]+arr[i];
    for(int j=1;j<=K;++j)
    {
        temp=sum[i]-sum[i-j];
        if(i-j-1>=0)
        temp+=including[i-j-1];
        if(temp>maxi)maxi=temp;
    }
    including[i]=maxi;
    excluding[i]=including[i-1];
}
printf("%lld",maxim(including[N-1],excluding[N-1]));
}

//here is the code...passing all but 1 test case :) comment improvements...simple DP
```