# find maximum sum of elements in an array such that not more than k elements are adjacent

Tags: algorithm

This is a duplicated of [Removal of billboards from given ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376976/removal-of-billboards-from-given-ones), I have read the answers to this question (and others) carefully, but i still cant wrap me head around it ? what is soulcheck mean in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376976/removal-of-billboards-from-given-ones/9377318#9377318) ?

I dont want code, I just want the algorithm explained in plain english.
and if an example is provided I'll greatly appreciate it .

Comment: I have added my answer in the original post. It would be too hard for me to explain in plain english, so I wrote some pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

He suggests to make and P[n,k] array, where P[i,j] would store the maximum possible value (profit) that could be obtained from the billboards 1..i (with some of them removed if necessary), so that there are exactly j consecutive billboards at the right side.

Edit:
By the way this solution doesn't meet the requirements of the problem (N <= 10^5)