# find maximum sum of n elements in an array such that not more than k elements are adjacent

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Almost the same as this:
[find maximum sum of elements in an array such that not more than k elements are adjacent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977663/find-maximum-sum-of-elements-in-an-array-such-that-not-more-than-k-elements-are)

except there is a limit of n elements we can choose. How to modify the DP algorithm to make it work for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, let me  make it more clearly.

question: find maximum sum of n elements in an array such that not more than K elements are adjacent

let *int f[i][j][k]* means the maximum sum for first i elements, using j total elements and the last k elements are used. let *bool g[i][j][k]* denotes whether it is possible to get certain combination. eg. g[1][1][2] is false. this is important because without restrict, f may generate **impossible** answers.

initially, memset f and g to be all zeros and set g[0][0][0] to be true. we can use forward recurrence to solve this DP problem. obviously, each time you encounter a number, you have two choices: choose it, or abadon it. thay gives out the recurrence formula:

```
f[i][j][k] can infer f[i+1][j+1][k+1], or
f[i][j][k] can infer f[i+1][j][0]
```

so, the pseudo code can be as follow:

```
memset(f,0,sizeof(f));
memset(g,0,sizeof(g));
g[0][0][0]=true;
for (int i=0;i<array.size();i++)
    for (int j=0;j<=n;j++)
        for (int k=0;k<=K;k++) if (g[i][j][k]) {
            f[i+1][j][0]=max(f[i+1][j][0],f[i][j][k]);
            f[i+1][j+1][k+1]=max(f[i+1][j+1][k+1],f[i][j][k]+array[i]);
            g[i+1][j][0]=true;
            g[i+1][j+1][k+1]=true;
        }
```

and the final result will be:

```
ans=0;
for (i=0;i<=K;i++)
    ans=max(ans,f[array.size()][n][i]);
return ans;
```

above gives **exactly j elements**. if you want to get **at most j elements**, you can change it in this way:

```
ans=0;
for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
    for (j=0;j<=K;j++)
        ans=max(ans,f[array.size()][i][j]);
return ans;
```

Comment: @WilliamRookwood first of all, i think i made a small mistake in my original code. i will edit my post shortly.

Comment: @WilliamRookwood Did I answer your question? Do you need more help?

Answer (score 4):

Add new dimension of DP function:
`f[i, j, l]` - max sum for first **i** elements, if used **j** total elements and **last l elements** in this sum.

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble figuring out the recurrence formulas, could you show the recurrence formula? Thanks

Comment: For example,
`P(v,i) = P(v-1,i-1) + C(v) if i > 0 `,

`P(v,0) = max(P(v-1,i) for i = 0..min(k, v)) `
,
`P(0,0) = 0`


 were the recurrence formulas in the other post I linked to. Can you provide the formulas for the f[i, j, l] function?